# Loading TensorFlow1 checkpoint in TensorFlow2 - "Function Call Stack: keras_scratch_graph"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to load a checkpoint from TensorFlow1 that consists of `.index`, `.meta`, `.data-00000-of-00001` files into `tensorflow2.0.0` and convert it to a keras model so to be able to use it natively in eager mode without need for `tf.Session`. Here is the code I ran:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.python.training.saver import _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements


def save_ckpt(ckpt_path='test'):
  '''save TensorFlow-1 Checkpoint '''
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    in_op  = tf.constant(np.random.rand(1,2,2,2),name='input',dtype=tf.float32)
    out_op = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,(3,3),padding='same',name='MY_LAYER')(in_op)
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(tf.compat.v1.global_variables()))
        saver.save(sess,ckpt_path)


def load_ckpt():
    '''KerasModel from meta & ckpt'''
    in_op = tf.keras.Input([2,2,2])
    _m = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=in_op,outputs=in_op)    
    with _m.input.graph.as_default() as g:
        saver, out_op =  _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements('test.meta',
                                      input_map={'input':_m.output},
                                      return_elements=[
                                                    # 'input:0',
                                                      'MY_LAYER/Conv2D:0'
                                                      ])
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
                saver.restore(sess,'test')
                set_session(sess)
                out_mdl = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=_m.input, outputs=out_op[0]) 
    return out_mdl


# main
save_ckpt()              # save name based checkpoint
meta_model = load_ckpt() # restore in keras model
oo = meta_model(np.random.rand(1,2,2,2)) # run the model
print(oo)
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question2.py", line 38, in <module>
    meta_model = load_ckpt() # restore in keras model
  File "question2.py", line 32, in load_ckpt
    out_mdl = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=_m.input, outputs=out_op[0]) 
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 146, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 167, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 270, in _init_graph_network
    base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 184, in create_keras_history
    _, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, set(), [])
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 229, in _create_keras_history_helper
    constants[i] = backend.function([], op_input)([])
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3740, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1081, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1121, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable MY_LAYER/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/MY_LAYER/kernel)
     [[node MY_LAYER/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp (defined at /home/dionyssos/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_72]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

**What I tried so far**

Replacing `MY_LAYER/Conv2D:0` with `input:0` in `_import_meta_graph_with_return_elements()` makes the code run with no problem.

Comment: Is there something special with `MY_LAYER/Conv2D:0` in your network that could make it be the only source of bug ? Is it the only Conv2D for example ?

Comment: The function `save_ckpt()` saves a checkpoint with a single conv2d layer called `MY_LAYER` that I try to restore as a toy example. I have the same error when loading any bigger network

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, I had'nt read this part of the code. Now what I don't get is when do you decide that you save the graph in `tf 1` and load it in `tf 2.0`

Comment: It is just that I have some pretrained models in `tf 1` format that I would like to use in `tf 2` without having to recode them from scratch

Comment: And when you trained it first, did you have any custom session config like `tf_config = some_custom_config; 
sess = tf.Session(config=tf_config)` ?

Comment: No. In fact the saving session is in `save_ckpt()` function in the code i posted. You can also add a `print(sess.run(out_op))` inside the `save_ckpt()` function to verify

Comment: Excuse me I misunderstood your question: In tensorflow1 most checkpoints were saved using `tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()` class which is what I'm trying to restore.